# What is the value of $\frac1{\cos18^{\circ}\sin9^{\circ}}+\frac1{\cos18^{\circ}\cos9^{\circ}}$?

Tags: trigonometry

> What is the value of
> $\dfrac1{\cos18^{\circ}\sin9^{\circ}}+\dfrac1{\cos18^{\circ}\cos9^{\circ}}$?
>
> $1)4\sqrt2\cot36^{\circ}\qquad\qquad2)2\sqrt2\cot36^{\circ}\qquad\qquad3)\dfrac{\cos54^{\circ}}{\cos36^{\circ}}\qquad\qquad4)\dfrac{\sin54^{\circ}}{\sin36^{\circ}}$

Here is my approach:

$$\frac1{\cos18^{\circ}\sin9^{\circ}}+\frac1{\cos18^{\circ}\cos9^{\circ}}=\frac{\cos9^{\circ}+\sin9^{\circ}}{\cos18^{\circ}\cos9^{\circ}\sin9^{\circ}}$$

$\dfrac{1}{\cos18^{\circ}\cos9^{\circ}\sin9^{\circ}}$ is equal to $\dfrac{4}{\sin36^{\circ}}$. Hence we have,

$$\frac{4(\cos9^{\circ}+\sin9^{\circ})}{\sin36^{\circ}}=\frac{4\sqrt{1+\sin18^{\circ}}}
{\sin36^{\circ}}$$

But I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: In general, it may help to remember that $\sin x + \cos x = \sqrt2 \ \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4} - x \right) = \sqrt2 \ \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4} + x \right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Multiply the num/denom of the first fraction by $2\cos(9^\circ)$ and the num/denom of the second fraction by $2\sin(9^\circ)$ and use $2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\ldots$

Comment: Thanks! But I will get $\frac{4(\cos9^{\circ}+\sin9^{\circ})}{\sin36^{\circ}}$ again at the end . Am I right?

Comment: @Soheil: Yes. Finish by using the sum formulas for $\sin$ and $\cos$

Comment: $$\cos(9^\circ)+\sin(9^\circ)=\sin(81^\circ)+\sin(9^\circ)=2\sin(45^\circ)\cos(36^\circ)=\ldots$$

Comment: This method is more elegant than using common denominator as I did. Furthermore I think it is better to multiply the first fraction by $4\cos(9^{\circ})$  and second one by $4\sin(9^{\circ})$ to get rid of fraction in denominators :)

Comment: @Soheil: Yes, I did just that in my scratchpad. It's a fairly common "chain-reaction" in trig: more generally, $\displaystyle2^n\sin(x)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos(2^k x)=\sin(2^n x)$. Another similar example is $\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(6^{2^k}+5^{2^k})=6^{2^n}-5^{2^n}$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)=$$
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(\theta-x)$$

if $ a=b=1 $ then
$$\theta=45^°$$
and
$$\cos(9°)+\sin(9°)=\sqrt{2}\cos(45-9)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sin 18^\circ = \cos 72^\circ$ and $\sqrt{1 + \cos 2\theta} = \sqrt{2 \cos^2\theta}.$ So your last fraction simplifies as $$\frac{4 \sqrt{2} \cos 36^\circ }{\sin 36^\circ} = 4 \sqrt{2} \cot 36^\circ.$$